# How do I make a for loop change each row instead of the whole column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has 1,500 observations. I created a column for low income, and I need to assign values based on the value of another variable.

What I want is that if the value on df$income is 4:13, the loop assigns value 1. Otherwise, if it's 14 :17, assign a value 0.

I have the loop like this:

```
low_inc <- NA

vote$low_inc <- low_inc

for(i in vote$income){
  if (vote$income == 4||5||6||7||8||9||10||11||12||13) {
    vote$low_inc <- 1
  } else if (vote$income == 14||15||16||17){
    vote$low_inc <- 0
  }
}
```

I think the issue is that I am changing the whole column instead of each individually.

Comment: Read about `?"%in%"`

Comment: You shouldn't need a loop here. Try: `vote$new <- as.integer(vote$income %in% 4:13)`. If there are values outside of 4:17 then you'll need more code and possibly `NA` values